# Checking for new action after android boot

Tags: android

I want to receive some notifications in android application like for example facebook or snapchat. When someone send me snap i get notification. 
I wrote a broadcast receiver, service and it worked. But my question is how the hell snapchat or facebook doing this? I don't see their services on the list in settings. But i can see my application service on this list. Is there some other magical way to do this?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html), instead of making every application running it's own service for notifications, google created GCM that is hosted on their server and active on your device via google services. When new message is arrived google will wake up your application for you.

This is what Facebook and everyone else do.